# can't remove persistent android widget (accuweather.com)

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, app-widgets

I am facing an annoying problem due to the widget called "accuweather.com". It pops up while I'm using applications on my phone (Samsung galaxy s2 with gingerbread 2.3.5). I can't uninstall it because the option isn't there, it is not a "downloaded" app but appears on the screen of all applications. When opening it there is an option to stop it (it runs as a service) but not to uninstall it, and shortly after stopping it, it would run again.

It is really like a malware and preventing me from using my phone propely. Please help, thanks.

Comment: It sounds more like a notification or possibly toast message rather than a widget (which simply lives on the home screen). Have you tried going into the app to see if it has any options for notifications?

Comment: Just to make sure: Do you have AccuWeather installed? And what does that popup say? Is it a simple text-line stating something like "weather update successful", or something else? A screenshot might be helpful.

Comment: As Izzy said, can you post a screen shot?

Answer (score 1):

I think it is a recent Accuweather update that displays the weather when you go back on your home menu. It's really annoying as when you click on the "home" button, it brings you back to that page and not the actual menu, which means you can't navigate between applications without clicking the back button all the way.

I think I may have fixed it the brute force way, however. I don't care about the Accuweather app, so I just went in the Setting->Applications->All menu and deactivated Accuweather altogether. You get a warning message telling you that deactivating built-in apps may interfere with other applications, but I hardly think that Accuweather is necessary for your phone to work.

Answer (score 1):

as you said, some of the apps cannot be uninstalled since it comes preloaded with the Samsung phone itself.

The other way to calm down an annoying app is to clear its data.

Goto :: Home -> Settings -> Applications -> All -> App Name (in this case, accuweather) -> Clear Data.

Wait for a day. if this solves the problem, then try using this app as usual.